# Nodejs child process max cpu`s as limit

Tags: node.js, multithreading, process, operating-system, child-process

i see a lot of examples ,libraries and even in the cluster documentations example 
that they limit the number of running process to the same number of cpu`s.

does creating a child_process will ensure getting the process thread pinned to a specific cpu or it just a recommendation for making the Os scheduler life easier ?

Comment: *pinned to a specific cpu* - which one? You don't specify it, so it's not pinned.

Comment: @estus i thought maybe in the node core code they pin the child_process threads. if not what the profit from limit the number of child process to the number of cpu?

Comment: *if not what the profit from limit the number of child process to the number of cpu?* - otherwise children would compete over same cores and possibly result in less efficient multithreading.

Comment: @estus but if they are not pined that mean they can still compete on the same core because each time the core will be selected by the Os scheduler  no ?

Comment: In some lousy OS, yes. It is the responsibility of OS to allocate resources efficiently. This isn't specific to Node child processes. The same would apply to any process in the system. Almost none of them is pinned to specific cores, yet when there is a number of single-thread processes that is equal to amount of cores, they are magically distributed among them and can achieve 100% CPU load.

Comment: @estus first thing thanks!!! this is great knowledge please put it as an answer so i can accept it. 
second node js is not rely single threaded there is also the gc thread and i guess libuv library that is part of the node code also has a thread pool in it doesnt they are also part of the core resource competition ?  sorry for all the questions i just want to understand the flow more deeply and its hard to find answers in google for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless affinity is set for a process, e.g. with [`nodeaffinity`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodeaffinity), the use of CPU cores is governed by OS. This is not specific to child processes or Node.js, the same applies to any process.

Maximum amount of children is set to a number of cores by default because a greater amount would result in processes competing over same cores and less efficient multithreading. The amount may vary in both directions depending on the benchmarks. Sometimes it may be beneficial to leave cores free for non-Node CPU intensive processes (e.g. database).

Comment: What does nodeaffinity do when you set the affinity within your nodejs program? Will all child-processes also be executed on the same set core? Or how do you set the affinity for the child_processes created via `spawn`?